# Jcov code coverage utility caused an error com.sun.javatest is missing

Tags: java, code-coverage, test-coverage

I'm trying to implement a code coverage measurement on a java application. I have used this command to build jcov utility

```html
ant -v -f build.xml -Dasmjar5=~/sans/jcov_artifacts/asm-5.0.1/lib/asm-5.0.1.jar -Djavatestjar=~/sans/jcov_artifacts/jtharness/lib/javatest.jar
```

But keep getting following error message saying sun is there anyway to add com.sun.javatest to package as jar file or what am i doing wrong? Any ideas? I am using **java 8** on **ubuntu 14.04**
and **asm-7.0 & jtharness-4.6.tar.gz**

```html
build-jt.observer:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/zebra/sans/jcov/JCOV_BUILD/temp/jcov_jtobserver_classes
    [javac] jcov/JTObserver.java added as jcov/JTObserver.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/zebra/sans/jcov/JCOV_BUILD/temp/jcov_jtobserver_classes
    [javac] Using modern compiler
dropping /home/zebra/sans/jcov/build/javatest.jar from path as it doesn't exist
    [javac] Compilation arguments:
    [javac] '-d'
    [javac] '/home/zebra/sans/jcov/JCOV_BUILD/temp/jcov_jtobserver_classes'
    [javac] '-classpath'
    [javac] '/home/zebra/sans/jcov/JCOV_BUILD/temp/jcov_jtobserver_classes'
    [javac] '-target'
    [javac] '1.7'
    [javac] '-encoding'
    [javac] 'iso-8859-1'
    [javac] '-g'
    [javac] '-source'
    [javac] '1.7'
    [javac] 
    [javac] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [javac] not part of the command.
    [javac] File to be compiled:
    [javac]     /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:27: error: package com.sun.javatest does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.javatest.Harness;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:28: error: package com.sun.javatest does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.javatest.Parameters;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:29: error: package com.sun.javatest does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.javatest.TestResult;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:30: error: package com.sun.javatest.TestResult does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.javatest.TestResult.Section;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:40: error: package Harness does not exist
    [javac] public class JTObserver implements Harness.Observer {
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void startingTestRun(Parameters prmtrs) {
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Parameters
    [javac]   location: class JTObserver
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void startingTest(TestResult tr) {
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class TestResult
    [javac]   location: class JTObserver
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void finishedTest(TestResult tr) {
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class TestResult
    [javac]   location: class JTObserver
    [javac] /home/zebra/sans/jcov/src/classes/jcov/JTObserver.java:78: error: package TestResult does not exist
    [javac]         tr.addObserver(new TestResult.Observer() {
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] 9 errors
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
/home/zebra/sans/jcov/build/build.xml:291: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1174)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 4 seconds
```

Comment: it clearly says that `/home/zebra/sans/jcov/build/javatest.jar` does not exist. either you should put `javatest.jar` into `/home/zebra/sans/jcov/build/` or you need to modify `-Djavatestjar`

Comment: @mangusta thanks, this was the error and it worked when i copied the javatest.jar file.